# Failed to instantiate module pageslide-directive with multiple pages in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning angularjs and i have created 2 pages namely welcome.html and queryboard.html. I was trying to implement side out panel, with help of this link
http://dpiccone.github.io/ng-pageslide/examples/ .

On my welcome page i was succesfully able to implement slideout panel. My welcome page has a carousel, on clicking the text on carousel it redirects to another page queryboard.html but when queryboard page is loaded it throws error on console

```
$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pageslide-directive due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pageslide-directive' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

Below is welcome.html

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/CarouselController.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/angular-pageslide-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/gsenv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: url(/resources/images/nyc.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    }

    .ng-pageslide {
        background: #ac2925;
    }

</style>
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" class="container-fluid col-md-12 col-md-offset-10" >
    <h1 class="text-center text-primary centered">Welcome to ananta-gs dashboard</h1>
    <div>
        <uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides" style="height: 305px; width: 450px; margin:auto">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
                <img ng-src="/resources/images/cloud-home.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <a href="#" ng-click='sendEnvName(slide.text)'>
                        <h3 class="carousel-caption text-primary center-block">
                            {{slide.text}}</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
        <a href="" style="background-color: #ac2925" ng-show="errorShow" ng-click="toggle()">There are exceptions during app initialization, click here to see details</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <pageslide ps-open="checked" ps-side="left" ps-squeeze="true">
            <div style="padding:20px" id="demo-right">
                <h2>Exceptions : </h2>
                <p style="word-wrap: break-word">{{exceptions}}</p>
                <a ng-click="toggle()" class="button">Close</a>
            </div>
        </pageslide>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js for queryboard.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, dataShare, $uibModal) {
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    $scope.errorShow = false;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.sendEnvName = function (data) {
        dataShare.sendEnvDetails(data);

        window.location.href = "query/queryboard.html";
    }

    $scope.addSlide = function (envName) {
        slides.push({
            text: envName,
            id: currIndex++
        });
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/getEnvList")
        .success(function (data) {
            var envs = data.spaceLookUpDetailsList;
            for (var i in envs) {
                $scope.addSlide(envs[i].envName);
            }


            if(data.exceptions) {
                $scope.errorShow = true;
                $scope.exceptions = data.exceptions;
            }
        })
        .error(function (errordata) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'error/ErrorModal.html',
                controller: 'ErrModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('error=' + errordata.errorMessage)
                        return errordata;
                    }
                }
            });


        });

    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
    }

});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ErrModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, error) {
    $scope.errormessage = error.errorMessage;
    $scope.stacktrace = error.stackTrace;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close('closed');
    };
});
```

below is queryboard.html

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../resources/js/angular-pageslide-directive.js.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/css">
    .app-modal-window .modal-dialog {
        width: 500px;
    }
</script>
<script src="../../../resources/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="../../../resources/js/TypeAheadController.js"></script>
<script src="../../../resources/js/gsenv.js"></script>
```

below is gsEnv.js, this is used to transfer data between multiple pages as a request parameter

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').factory('dataShare', function ($window) {
    var KEY = 'GS.SelectedENV';
    var sendEnvDetails = function (data) {
        var mydata = $window.sessionStorage.getItem(KEY);
        mydata = data;
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(KEY, JSON.stringify(mydata));
    };
    var getData = function () {
        var mydata = $window.sessionStorage.getItem(KEY);
        if (mydata) {
            mydata = JSON.parse(mydata);
        }
        return mydata || [];
    };
    return {
        sendEnvDetails: sendEnvDetails,
        getData: getData
    };
});
```

Is angularjs only for SPA, or do i need to declare separate app for each html page and will it support data transfer between multiple pages

Comment: Why would you mix html and jsp?

Comment: @NexusDuck...it was a typo both pages are html